# Strange problem (lvs invocation) with grub on Debian Stretch

Tags: debian

When I've tried to issue update-grub command I saw very strange output:

```
update-grub
Generating grub configuration file ...
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-4.9.0-6-amd64
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-4.9.0-6-amd64
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-4.9.0-4-amd64
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-4.9.0-4-amd64
File descriptor 7 (pipe:[33660]) leaked on lvs invocation. Parent PID 7587: /bin/sh
done
```

I need to fix this problem. What can cause such message to appear?

Comment: This is a warning, not an error.

Comment: Very fine, but I want to get rid from this warning. Noticed strange behavior yesterday. After several server reboots this warning was gone, but today it is back again:/

Comment: I have a couple hundred VMs, seen this message for years, never made any difference

Answer (score 4):

These warnings point out some "untidiness" in the code somewhere between `update-grub` and the `lvs` binary: `lvs` inherited an open file descriptor (7) beyond the standard ones (0, 1 and 2). It closes all such descriptors right away printing a warning (which can be suppressed by the `LVM_SUPPRESS_FD_WARNINGS` environment variable). Letting descendant processes inherit file descriptors unnecessarily is bad coding practice, because it opens the door for exploits. So there really is something to fix here, though it probably has no security (or correctness) implications in this case.

Comment: Right, this is basically `lvm` developers being careful enough to inspect the environment that's executing the `lvm` binary. And when they detect something weird (open files passed from previous process to `lvm` binary) they emit this warning. The problem is not in `lvm` but the process that runs before it and fails to cleanup the process memory before executing `lvm`.